# Read a huge Oracle table using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark version: 2.4.7

OS: Linux RHEL Fedora

I have the following use case:

Read an oracle table that contains ~150 million records (Done Daily), and then write these records to 800 files (using repartition) on a shared file system to be used in another application.
I can read the table into a data frame, but when trying to write it never finishes.

```
 df
res38: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ROW_ID: string, CREATED: string ... 276 more fields]
```

When I limit the number of retrieved records to 1 million, and repartition by (6) the process to read and write takes 2-3 minutes.
I searched for insights on the issue but couldn't figure it out, when running the process on the full data set I see in the UI logs the following line (keeps repeating) :

> Blockquote

INFO sort.UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 135 spilling sort data of 5.2 GB to disk (57  times so far)

I submit the job using the following:

```
time  spark-submit --verbose --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --conf spark.spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=1000 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1500 --conf "spark.ui.enabled=true" --master yarn --driver-memory 60G --executor-memory 10G  --num-executors 40 --executor-cores 8 --jars ojdbc6.jar SparkOracleExtractor.jar
```

Please note there are enough resources on the cluster and the queue is only 5.0% used, and a constraint is to use Spark.

Appreciate any help on where to get information to resolve the issue and speed up the process.

This is the code:

```
val myquery = "select * from mytable"
val dt=20221023
spark.read.format("jdbc").
           option("url", s"jdbc:oracle:thin:@$db_connect_string").
           option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").
           option("query", myquery).
           option("user", db_user).
           option("password", db_pass).
           option("fetchsize", 10000).
           option("delimiter", "|").
           load()
df.repartition(800).write.csv(s"file:///fs/extrat_path/${dt}")
```

These are the shuffle spill sizes after 2.5 hours:

Shuffle Spill (Memory)  Shuffle Spill (Disk)

```
        259.4 GB         22.0 GB
```

Comment: Remember that Dataframe are lazy, when you evaluate `df` it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you share the code you use to read then write?

Comment: @Gaël J: The code is added